# How to get items from a list > than X

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function called "first_funtion()" that returns a list of 100 instances of a class.
Then I want to define a second function that is going to create a new list with random instances taken from the output list of first_function(), something like:

```
first_funtion()

def second_function(list2, N):
    list2 = list2(random.choice(first_function()))
```

The thing is that I want list2 to be always greater than N, so if N = 5 I want the random list2 to be more than 5 instances. If N = 10 then I want the list to be more that 10 instances.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use [numpy's random choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html?highlight=choice#numpy.random.choice) to do a sampling with replacement, meaning that an element can be in the `list2` more than once.

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. You want list2 to consist of  >N elements randomly chosen from the first list. You say 'I want list2 to be always greater than N' but you do not indicate what the upper bound on the number of elements is. Do you want a random number of elements in list2 between `N+1` and `len(list1)` (where `list1` is the list returned by `first_function()`)?

Answer (score 3):

You can first create the list using `first_function`, then draw a random integer in the range between `N` and the length of the list and then draw a random sample from the list.

```
import random

def second_function(list2, N):
    len_list = len(list2)
    length = random.randint(N, len_list)
    return random.sample(list2, length)
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly then this should be `length = random.randint(N+1, len_list)` since the OP said they want 'list2 to be always greater than N' instances.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using two *random* function;

- Use first one to choose a value of ***N*** from the range excluding ***N*** to including lenght of list1, i.e, (N, len(list1)]

  ```
   x = random.randint(N+1, len(list1)
  ```
- And use second one to choose ***x*** number of values from ***list_1***;

  ```
   random.choices(list1, k=x)
  ```

So, the code will look something like this:

```
import random

def second_function(list1, N):
   x = random.randint(N+1, len(list1))
   y = random.choices(list1, k=x)
   print(y)
```

Here `randint(start, stop)` includes both start and stop numbers while generating random integer. It will generate a random number from the *inclusive* range.

And`random.choices ()` function returns total *k* number of random items from any list.

**Note:** You may get repeated values if you're using `random.choices ()`. So, use  `random.sample()` function when you want to choose multiple random items from a list without repetition or duplicates.

You can visit on [this](https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/) link and explore more related to this.

Answer (score 1):

As the `random.choice()` function always picks one element from the list, so you can iterate through the list more than N number of times and use `random.choice()` each time. And you can also use `random.randint()` to get a random number above N, to be used in the range function for the `for` loop.

```
import random

def second_function(list2, N):
    for i in range(N,random.randint(N,len( first function() ))) :
        list2.append(random.choice(first_function()))
    return list2
```